# How do I use the info submitted in a form to create a form reception page? (like "thank you {firstName}")

Tags: forms

I'm using Elementor, and when I make a form, I have an "Actions After Submit" section. I'd like to be able to send the form data to another page, and then on that page, make an Elementor template to receive the information, something like.

"Hey, thank you {firstName}, for subscribing to our newsletter" or "Thank you for your order, here's a verification of the terms you submitted" and adding all the fields that the person submitted.

In the 'Actions After Submit', there seems to be a webhook option. That may be part of the solution, to simply have Elementor put the details of the form into another page, and have that page process it with PHP, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution, or even a feasible one, especially since I'm using a page builder.

What would you recommend that I do in this case?